# Lightbox Not Loading on Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver, lightbox

I'm not sure if anyone here will want to help with this, but I would be really, really, really grateful! This is the first webpage I've ever built, I'm a complete newbie, but I'm definitely learning a lot in this process.

I'm using DreamWeaver CS4 on a Mac. I'm trying to get a lightbox gallery to work. I'd just like a simple page of thumbnails, and when you click one the larger image appears in a lightbox. I have galleries on the other pages on the site that I got working using Adobe Bridge, but I don't like them because they don't work on the iphone. Right now when you click on the thumbnails they just open in a new page with no lightbox effect.

I downloaded lightbox from [Lokesh Dhakar](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). I also downloaded jQuery. Here's the page I've been trying to get lightbox to work on: http://www.greencommamedia.com/logos.html

I thought I had solved the problem when I saw I'd misspelled "lightbox" as "lighbox", but I think I fixed that (though I really can't be sure, is it other places in the code?). I tried to check that the path to lightbox.css is correct. I also changed this path in the lightbox index. Is there something else I need to add to the code to make this work? Have I completely messed it up and need to start over? I realize my code is a complete MESS (DreamWeaver, and this is the first time I've tried anything like this!).

I would really appreciate any pointers or help getting this working. Thank you!!

My code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#linkline {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F60;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F00;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#center {
    text-align: center;
}
.abouttext {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#abouttext {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#abouttext td p span {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#center a {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.copyright {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
div.img a:hover img {
    background-color: #lightgrey;
}
div.desc {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 120px;
}
body, ul, li, img {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
#logos {
    width: 500px;
    text-align:center;
}
#logos li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
}
#logos a img {
    border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}
#logos a:hover img {
    border: 5px solid #aaa;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/jquery.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
</style>
<title>logos</title>
<link href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="745" id="center"><img src="images/greencommalogo.jpg" alt="logo" width="700" height="200" border="0" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="33" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" font-size="18px" id="center"><a href="index.html">HOME</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="portfolio.html">WORK</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<link href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="logos">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="images/logos/3handlogoLiteracy1ad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/3handlogoLiteracy1_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/logos/circlepencilad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/circlepencil_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/logos/farmerlogoad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/farmerlogo_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/logos/handlogoad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/handlogo_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/logos/linemanad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/lineman_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/logos/Logo5ad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/Logo5_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/logos/storylinessealad.jpg" rel="data-lightbox"><img src="images/logosthumbnails/storylinesseal_jpg.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Copyright &copy; 2014 Green Comma Media</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

UPDATE: As one helpful commenter pointed out, lightbox.js does not seem to be loading. When looking at the network tab, I get the error message Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined logos.html:107(anonymous function). As far as I can tell, lightbox.js is loaded and where it should be. Is there some language I need to add to my code to make it work? Thank you for any help.

Comment: first of all some of the images are not there http://www.greencommamedia.com/lightbox/img/close.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), http://www.greencommamedia.com/lightbox/img/loading.gif
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), http://www.greencommamedia.com/lightbox/img/prev.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), http://www.greencommamedia.com/lightbox/img/next.png

Comment: where is lightbox js, i am thinking you are not refering here

Comment: Hi Manjunath Siddappa. I don't know, did I link it correctly? I thought it was linked with this line? <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>

Comment: open your website in chrome press f12 in network tab CTRL+F see lightbox js is available or not??? i dont think you have it.

Comment: Thank you for that, Manjunath! My img folder wasn't inside the lightbox folder. I moved it in thinking that would solve the problem, but it still doesn't work... Any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: it should be `lightbox/img/loading.gif`

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but what's the network tab? How do I get there specifically and what exactly am I looking for? Thank you!!!

Comment: in network tab, you can see what are the css is loaded, javascript, images and json. refer this http://superuser.com/questions/721021/filter-on-request-type-in-chrome-dev-tools-network-tab

Comment: also this http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console--net-28167

Comment: Okay, I looked in the network tab. I do see see something with the name loading.gif.

Comment: I don't see anything that says lightbox.js, though--is that supposed to be there somewhere? What do I do. Thank you!

Comment: yes it should be there, try to put outside. for Eg: put lightbox.js near to html you are loading, if it is working fine, then work around on setting the path.

Comment: What do you mean "put it near to the html"? How do I know if it's working fine? I just tried putting lightbox.js again, but nothing changed. Then I tried adding a new line in my code, <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script> but lightbox still doesn't work and it just messed up the formatting? I still don't understand exactly what I need to do. Thank you so much for helping with this!!